# What does it mean to find minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over some $F[\alpha]$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, polynomial-rings

I am asked to find the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F[\alpha]$. I understand what it means to find minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F[x]$ but what does it mean to find it over $F[\alpha]$ since this is not even a polynomial ring?

Comment: "The minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $H$" is an expression that takes in for $H$ a *field* (not a polynomial ring) and for $\beta$ an element of some ring/field extension of $H$, and it indicates the monic polynomial $p\in H[x]$ of least degree such that $p(\beta)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a field $K$, and an element $\beta$ that's algebraic over $K$, you can be tasked with finding the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$. If this $K$ happens to be an extension of a smaller field, such as $F[\alpha]$ which is an extension of $F$, that doesn't really change anything.

This minimal polynomial of $\beta$ will be an element of $K[x] = F[\alpha][x]$, but we do not say that it is the minimal polynomial "over" $K[x]$. It is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K = F[\alpha]$.

As a simple example, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]2$ over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ is $x^2 - \sqrt2$, which is an element of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2][x]$. And the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]5$ over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt[6]3]$ is $x^3 - 5\in \Bbb Q[\sqrt[6]3][x]$.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. I was confused as it didn't state anywhere in my book we find the polynomial over $F[\alpha][x]$.

Comment: @Axo I admit, writing something like $F[\alpha][x]$ feels a little strange. It is not something that I have done many times, because at that stage you would often just leave the definition of the polynomial ring implicit. As it seems your book has. But it is what we have here. We have the field $F[\alpha]$, and then we look for an element in the polynomial ring where the coefficients come from that field.